# python genfromtext specify some dtype but leave others for automatic determination

Tags: python, numpy

I do not understand why numpy.genfromtext allows you to specify only all or none of the dtypes.  I am trying to let it do the obvious (default) thing for most fields, but to specify some that I think it will have difficulty with.  In general, I do not know the complete list of fields in my data file.
Is there a better way to do this than load in the file twice, as follows?

```
dtypeoverrides={'textfield':'a20','anotherTrickyfield':'a10','nonexisting field':'a1'}
tsv='inputfile.tsv'

indata=np.genfromtxt(tsvF, delimiter='\t',names=True,dtype=None)

if dtypeoverrides:
   dd=indata.dtype
   print dd
   dd=[(name,dtypeoverrides.get(name,dd[name])) for name in dd.names]
   print dd
   indata=np.genfromtxt(tsvF, delimiter='\t',names=True,dtype=dd)
```